# JSON Schema Validation Failing ... "The property did not contain a required property"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec, jsonschema

Below is a partial version of my json schema. I currently am using the `json-schema` Gem to validate the following (partial) schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "botSettings": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "welcomeMessage": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": ["body"],
          "properties": {
            "title": { "type": "string" },
            "body": { "type": "string" },
            "image": { "#ref": "#/definitions/image" }
          }
        },
        "invalidCommandMessage": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

against the following (partial) json:

```
{
  "botSettings": {
    "welcomeMessage": {
      "title": "Welcome to the bot",
      "body": "This is the body right here"
    }
  }
}
```

When validating in strict mode, it states "The property '#/botSettings/welcomeMessage' did not contain a required property of 'image'", however I only have required set to "body". So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything.  A standard JSON Schema validator should consider your JSON valid.  Failure to validate could be either a bug in the validator, some non-standard behavior in the validator (check configuration), or it's not validating against the schema you think it is (cache issue).

Answer (score 0):

You write that you are using strict mode. On the json-schema github page, I found the following:

> with the `:strict` option, all properties are considered to have
> `"required": true` and all objects `"additionalProperties": false`